# Fullscreen with opengl

Tags: opengl, fullscreen

I need my window to be set to fullscreen (**fs**). No border, no interaction with anything behind this window, no start bar,etc. Just the program i'll be working in.

I'm guessing that the cursor not going outside of the window is not part of this, but i'll work on that later.

I've seen and tried the NeHe tutorial, but since it was wrote almost 10 years ago, i was wondering if a "less-line" way of putting a program **fs** exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "less-line" way of putting a program fs exist.

Use [glut](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/) or [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/) and initialize them in fullscreen mode. Can't get less lines than that.

Otherwise read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400654/how-do-i-put-my-opengl-app-into-fullscreen-mode).

Comment: actually now that i think of it, the number of line wouldn't really matter, but just a good way to have a fullscreen.

And the link was actually the question i still fell on each time i searched. I guess i'll go with NeHe and adapt the bit of code i've already done to it.

Comment: @CédrickLemay: The "good" way, IMO is to use a cross-platform library that'll do the job for you, because this way you will not be tied to a single platform.

Comment: I'll go with Nehe for now. I'll try the cross-platform on my next similar project. Thanks!

Comment: So great a simplified updated GLUT project...   glutFullScreen() and done!!